# Rewrite the base-url for single posts

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to append the URL when viewing a single post. 
For example when im on a post I want the url to be something like: `example.com/mypage/mypage/single-post-article`

The default url is `example.com/single-post-article`

I did not find something here on WPSE or the goooglz, but I have read about `wp-rewrite` and tried `add_post_type_support` to the `post` but no luck!

```
add_post_type_support( 'post', array(
   'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/bla/bla/')
));
```

Do I need to use `wp_rewrite`?

**Update**

I did get this to work by run `register_post_type` on the post_type "post" again. But is this the best way?

```
  register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/mypage/mypage' ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'pages'     => false,
        'supports' => array( 
            'title', 
            'editor',
            'author', 
            'thumbnail', 
            'excerpt', 
            'revisions
        ),
));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to your Settings > Permalinks page and set your permalinks to:

```
/mypage/mypage/%postname%/
```

If you don't want categories to append `/mypage/mypage`, you can change their permastruct:

```
function wpa85084_category_permastruct(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['category']['struct'] = '/category/%category%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa85084_category_permastruct' );
```

Comment: one remark regarding Milo answer, i tryed it, it work's but how about the author, tags ...etc the permalink structure affect all the website not only the posts, so how to restrict it to only posts ?

Comment: Setting permalinks does work but it seems to conflict with 404 errors. When I change my permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%/ ` then all 404 errors redirect to homepage instead of showing my custom 404 template. Does anybody have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try flushing your rewrite rules after you defined them?

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: You should always add a caveat with this that it should only be done _once_, so doing it via code is dangerous. Personally, I always flush my rewrites by updating the permalinks on the permalinks settings page.