# Rewrite URL for single category

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a site displaying posts on 2 parent pages: Blog and Ask Anything.
They are both using the default WordPress post, but the blog displays all categories excluding "Ask Anything", and the Ask Anything page displays only that category.

Is it possible for the blog posts to have the URL of "blog/postname", and the Ask Anything posts to have the URL of "ask-anything/postname"?

Maybe this is a job for `wp_rewrite`, but I haven't found the solution yet. [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85084/rewrite-the-base-url-for-single-posts) seemed promising, but I didn't see any change in my URL's. Currently the permalinks are set to a custom structure of andrewarthur.info/dev/blog/%postname%/.

Note: I originally set out to make the Ask Anything posts a custom post type, which would solve this whole issue. There are many solutions I found that addressed custom taxonomy. But I was having difficulty displaying a list of the custom posts, and the project timeline won't allow for further development in that direction just yet.

You can [check out the site here](http://andrewarthur.info/dev/blog/) for reference.

Comment: using a custom post type is far easier than what you're asking for, not sure why you had issues with that.

Comment: @Milo I was having trouble displaying a list with the custom post type category. If anyone could point me in the right direction for how to achieve that, I would try it again.

Comment: if it's just a custom post type, I'm not sure how categories would be involved. register a post type and set `has_archive` to `ask-anything`, go to `domain.com/ask-anything/` and you will see your list of posts.